# "Dynamic" Choice on SelectInput in Shiny

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

```
selectInput(
  inputId = "histvariable", 
  label = "Select a variable",
  choices = list("Age", "SibSp", "Parch", "Fare")
)
```

I would like to ask if I can make the `choices` more "dynamic"?  What I mean is that `choices` can select all variables from a .csv file.  The example code above is only selecting four variables (`Age`, `SibSp`, `Parch`, `Fare`) from the .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet for a `SelectInput` based on the colnames of an uploaded csv file.

```
library(shiny)
  ui = fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("“Dynamic” Choice on SelectInput in Shiny
  ",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   fileInput('file1', 'Upload your  CSV File'),
                   htmlOutput("varselectOne")),
                 mainPanel(
                    verbatimTextOutput("rendertext")
                 )))))


  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    myData1 <- reactive({
      inFile <- input$file1
      if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
      data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep=",")
      data
    })

    #observe(print(myData1()))

    output$varselectOne <- renderUI({
      #browser()
      req(myData1())
      # Variable selection:
      selectInput(inputId = "varsOne", label = "Variables to use:", choices=names(myData1()), selected=names(myData1()), multiple =FALSE)
    })

     output$rendertext <- renderPrint ({
      req(input$varsOne) #To ensure values are available before proceeding with a calculation or action, 
                         #and prevent ?renderPrint from through an error before file uploaded
      input$varsOne
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I received the value of "NULL" when I run renderPrint(input$varsOne) even after I upload the .csv file.  Please advise

Comment: @GaryFung it works, it shows NULL before the file gets uploaded "I fixed with `req(input$varsOne)`" but then variable name gets printed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  It works now.  Meanwhile I would like to ask one more question.  If I save your code above in for example a file called app.R, how do I call app.R in another .Rmd file?  Please advise.